# dynamic loading of JavaScript files in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, karma-runner

How can I include a set of JS files in my Karma Config  that are dynamically loaded in my code?

I'm not sure how I can load those files dynamically. We are trying to avoid having to download them and maintain them separately.

Google hasn't helped much so some help would be great.

Comment: Why you want to load them separately ?

Comment: You mean JS module to load dinamically?

Comment: I mean any JS library that is loaded via a URL or via a function call. How are those dealt with Karma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a js file that loads them and add this to the list of files in the karma conf somewhere near the top.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to do this kind of thing:

1. Include the files in the `files` array, specifying a pattern and setting `include` to false.

   Have a look [to the RequireJS page on the Karma website](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html) for an
   idea on how this works.
2. Use proxies. Have a look [on the Karma configuration page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html).